# Android Wear - How to stream audio input from phone to wearable?

Tags: android, audio, stream, wear-os

In my app I want to stream the microphone input from my phone to a wearable device.

I am fine already with sending messages (MessageAPI) but I am not sure how the streaming of audio can be implemented.

As far as I understand there is the ChannelAPI for sending larger files, but I am not sure this is the way to go for sending a stream.
Is there any other solution?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ChannelApi for streaming as well; it has APIs to open a channel and provide you with an [OutputStream](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Channel#getOutputStream(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) on the sender side and an [InputStream](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/Channel#getInputStream(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)) on the receiver side; using those you should be able to stream from one node to another.